# How can I determine what is in my water?

Tags: water, faucet, health-and-safety, filter, taps

My question is, how can I determine exactly what these "floaties" are that I see in my drinking water?  I know that I sound crazy and more than a little obsessive-compulsive....my wife tells me this all the time.

For a while, we had a Brita water pitcher that had a replaceable filter in it, and it works great except that bits of the charcoal would always fall into the reservoir (even after following instructions on how to clean it out after replacing it with a brand new filter, etc).  We never had "floaties", other than the little grains of charcoal, which still drove me crazy (to the point that I would dump the water or use it for something else, clean out the reservoir, and fill it up again...).

Whenever I get water from the tap in a glass, I raise it up to the light to see what's in it.  Normally there are a bunch of air bubbles, which is fine.  But after letting the cup sit on the counter (covered with saran wrap to stop dust from falling in, etc), I've checked it again and have seen little "floaties".

We rent our home, and the refrigerator has a filtered water system (where you can replace a cylindrical water filter located inside the refrigerator).  The water tap for this is on the inner part of the refrigerator door (as opposed to on the outside...first time I've ever seen this).  Checking the water in the same manner as I do with the tap, holding it up to the light and inspecting it, results in little "floaties" in there also.

I live in Southern Arizona, USA, so we have a lot of sediment buildup in our water.  Using vinegar or "Lime Away" type products to remove buildup around faucets is a normal thing done every couple of months.

However, the filter that is in the refrigerator, even when replaced, still has "floaties" in the water, which leads me to believe that it may either be sediment, or something living in between the dispenser head and the filter itself.

I like to think of myself as a "manly man" - I like to get dirty, romp around, and have a good time.  But for some reason (a mental one, I'm sure), I cannot drink water that has "floaties" in it.  And if I can't/don't check for "floaties", I feel like there's something in the back of my throat that makes me want to sick up.

So anyway...any DIY way to find out what these floaties are?  I'm sure that it'll be cheaper than a shrink or a separate filtration solution...

Comment: Could it be that the "floaties" are coming from the glass (unrinsed dish soap, dust, etc.), and not the water itself?

Comment: When I was visiting my wife's family in Poland, where they bottle the municipal supply as mineral water (It's THAT good!) I noticed white lime sediments if I let it stand for a while.

Comment: It's likely harmless chemicals and/or minerals (calcium, sodium, potassium, fluoride, magnesium, bicarbonate, nitrate, chloride, sulfide, silica, etc.).  Warm water allows more things to dissolve in it, as it cools the dissolved materials solidify which could lead to visible particles.

Comment: If you're on a municipal water supply, you should be able to get a water quality report from them.

Comment: Are you on municipal water or your own supply?

Comment: Municipal.  While the town is rather small town (population as of 2007 was 43,000 over 272 square miles), if that matters at all.  I know folks who live on the outskirts of town who use their own wells, but that all gets filtered once it hits their house.  It could be mineral buildup, but I'd like to be certain...mainly because if if I can get some proof of what it is, I won't be so damned nuts about it.

Comment: Then the water is presumably safe, so it's only an aesthetic issue. Not sediment, sediment doesn't float. I think it's organic residue from the water source. Something like bleached algae "skeletons". It's been treated, so safe to consume, but sort of icky to think about. Just use a filter system that removes it.

Answer (score 2):

I would venture a guess that @Tester101's suspicion about your floaties coming from your glass (unrinsed soap, dust, etc.) may be heading down the right path. I would try rinsing a glass, scrubbing it with a new sponge or clean washcloth, wiping it dry with a clean towel (not paper towel, as this may leave pieces of paper behind), and then refilling it.  @NiallC's comment about asking for a water report from your municipal water supply is a pretty good alternative, but doesn't factor in anything that may come from the pipes between them and you. Most health departments will do water testing, so you could always fill a bottle and take it in.

Beyond that, if you really have to know what's in the water, your only real solution to absolutely know with 100% certainty (technically, unless you watch the health department do the tests, and can verify their results, you can't KNOW that they're right...but I'd probably just accept it) is to get [testing kits for this, that, and the other thing](http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/water-quality-testing-kits/water-quality-testing/test-instruments/ecatalog/N-bfi) (that was just the first page offering a wide range of kits that I found), that operate similar to what you might use for pool water. Depending on the sensitivity levels, you may pick up on things like trace amounts of chlorine...but of course this is going to get back into the more expensive end of things, as those kits aren't cheap (Grainger's seem to run around $40-$50 and up...it's about $20 for their cheapest, which is testing for copper, on that first page of results).

You could pick up a pool test kit, which will cover a couple of parameters (chlorine, calcium, hardness, etc.), but it's not going to cover everything and may not operate in the range you need to identify your floaties...it's designed primarily to help you maintain clear-looking pool water that you're not drinking, not crystal clear tap water.

So really:

- Ask for report from municipal water supply
- Take in sample to health department
- If you're still paranoid and want to know what it is, buy test kits
- If you just want to get rid of the floaties, filter, filter, filter, and make sure your dishes aren't the source

Comment: While the OP is not looking to filter the water, I do also live in AZ as the OP does (Phoenix) and an RO unit works wonders to address the municipal water supply. I have never seen a floater or other type of item within my water since purchasing the RO unit.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are concerned about the microbiology of your water you need to contact your local health department to check it out.**

-Simple test strips can only identify PH, acidity and metals that are **dissolved** within the water. Testing the floaties requires professional inspection like health laboratories and specific area related data.

---

**To remove excessive debris / silt / and dissolved chemicals**

- If you are happy that the water is not a hazard to your health and the only problem is some debris from pipes and or "charcoal??"(i think you mean carbon!) then installing a 2 stage filter on the main inlet of the house.. or at the tap that you intend to fill up on your drinking/cooking water.

[image]

The 2 stage filter consists of

1- 5Micron filter or spun polyster to remove particles such as silt / "flaoties"
2- Carbon block - removes smells and chlorine from water

---

**Commercial Solutions**

If you star searching for designs like this- you will come accros manyu RO (Reverse Osmosis) filter that describe PURE drinking water. In my opinion and many others it is considered that  drinking RO (reverse osmosis / distilled water) is not healthy! The other half will disagree- but they usually have some money to make out of it and these untis cost more than they should!

**[Interesting blog article. read about the water](http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/mystery-of-why-coke-is-bad-for-your.html)**

[image]

A setup like this is used because RO filter takes absolute ages to filter water. removing the RO membrane allows normal flow.

A simple 2 stage filter should not cost you much and the filter media needs changin 6 months if used daily and about 12 months on occasion. It is important to note that none of the media releases toxins into the water once it is saturated.

The tank of water outside - you could install a prefilter mesh that is carbon activated; but just make sure its not toxic.

Goodluck

Comment: Do you have a source that isn't a blog? I have seen no scientific studies showing reverse osmosis water is unhealthy.

Comment: You have to dig deeper. Like the blog says.. there is mixed content out there.. people selling RO units say its the best water for you.. other studies will imply that pure water should only be used for detoxyfing the body no longer than 8 - 12 weeks. I personally know RO water (pure water) causes health issues if used in long term

Comment: PS Why downvote- this solution is very viable, especially if used with a 4 stage filter that also purifies bacterial impurications. And no need to test water as its PURE 99.99% no bacteria no floaties.

Comment: I downvoted because you're spreading unsubstantiated rumor. Unless/until you can back up your claims regarding RO/distilled water, I personally cannot support your answer. The only thing that article (and the sales pitch it links to) does is spread FUD. I would like to see unbiased scientific study regarding the matter. The best I can find is that, sans flouride, people appear to have worse teeth (again, no study, just anecdotal evidence from dentists).

Comment: Also, OP originally specifically asked for a way to identify his floaties, not for a whole new filtration system.

Comment: Aigh! But he said he is more obsessive compulsive and would rather not have them there..+ charcaol?? so my answers specifically addresses the problem of removing the debris. Identifying fauna in water cannot be done with a test strip- if its greenish its most likely algae.. if its another colour it is bacteria/virus related or metal inhibited and needs PROFESSIONAL INSPECTION- I feel like I am repeating myself

Comment: I think saying that RO water is causing health issues without any additional explanation is just pure definition of spreading FUD.

Since water coming from those filters lacks most minerals (many of which are beneficial to our health) found in unfiltered water, you need to either compensate for those minerals with supplements or remineralize the water (I'm not sure how effective this is). Don't spread unjustified rumours without reading up on the matter first. "I personally know" does not automatically grant you authority :)

Comment: I did read up about it, extensively and even had bad experience that I learnt from. Unfortunaly a few fish died because I thought pure water (without any minerals) would be healthy. It sucked the life out of the fish. I was traumatised and read up extensively on it. Pure water is toxic (just like pure oxygen) - It needs a balance of minerals and alkaline. giving it a neutral PH and prevents inhabitation of more minerals(the effect of water sucking in what's around it- very bad!) Water filtered with carbon is the best solution. RO water is very specific and should not be consumed.udpated link

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [drinking water test kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FBMAVQ) to prove to yourself that it's safe. Note, I have no personal experience with this since I trust the tests done by my municipality.

[image]

Comment: Water testing is great for ensuring water is safe to drink, but unless the floaties happen to consist of whatever the test kit tests for, we will be no closer to identifying what the floaties are. It's possible to do an exhaustive lab analysis, but that can be really expensive. It will be good to know that the floaties are safe to consume and it's just an aesthetic issue.

Comment: Agreed, it won't tell you what they are, but if you're paranoid and considering filtering your water, this may help put your mind at ease.

Comment: That's a crummy kit, it won't give definitive results.

Comment: @Bryce But the package says "premium" so it must be good! :) If you've got a different product recommendation, I'm happy to change the link. Though I'm not suggesting a specific product, only pointing out that these test kits exist.

Comment: I've used a couple of these kits when my well was contaminated by groundwater and I've used them after chlorinating and flushing the well to make sure everything was okay.  The results agreed quite well with a  test that I had done by my county, although the county tested for more stuff.  The county's test was a couple hundred dollars.